# Using CSS3 how to animate the multiple `background-image` for different view ports

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 18 steps of different animation state as separate images. since i am using fluid layout, i don't know the height and width of the `view-port`, I want to animate the background image, that should work on all sizes, how to make that?

In this case i can't use the single background image. because in the empty space the repeat of of the image became visible. (if there is a idea to hide let me know)

for a sample i created a `3` step animation for solution. any one help me to animate this 3 images on different view ports with same time duration?

here is my code :

```
<h1>View Port 1</h1>
    <div class="vp1">
        <img width="100%" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/BgTransition/spacer.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <h1>View Port 2</h1>

    <div class="vp2">
        <img width=100% src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/BgTransition/spacer.png" alt="">
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
div.vp1 {
  max-width : 5em;
  max-height:5me;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/BgTransition/bg1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  /*background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/BgTransition/bg2.png);*/
  /*background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/BgTransition/bg3.png);*/
  background-size:cover;
}

div.vp2 {
  max-width :80%;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/BgTransition/bg1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  /*background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/BgTransition/bg2.png);*/
  /*background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/BgTransition/bg3.png);*/
  background-size:content;
}
```

there is 2 images `commented here`. how can i make smooth animation `moving from let to right the bar'?

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lqEHL453bRU8NHcBHV74?p=preview)

if not possible then how to do with javascript?

Comment: First off your demo doesn't work as the `img` tag on the second viewport isn't correctly formed.  Secondly, I don't really understand what you want it to do? Also your CSS isn't correct there is no such unit of measurement as `me`

Comment: I am not using img tag here. the purpose of the `img` tag to have some space according to the width or size of window. this is my mistake i used instead of `em`  with `me`. i requirement is how to animate multiple state of bg for animation.

Comment: What do you mean by animate?!  Do you want it to run, walk, fly, drive, flip, spin?!

Comment: yes, the first image has 1st step of the animation, and second has the second stop of the animation and 3 has third. how can i change the background image to make an animation?

Comment: How can the 2 images be 2 steps if they are in different viewports?  What do you want the animation to do?  Do you want to fade out image 1, then fade in image 2 etc etc?

Comment: No, this is a `bar` like. that's move from let to right. To understand exactly, please open each of the image urls and you will find the different steps.

Comment: I tried with javascript's `setTimeout` to change the image bg with some interval time. it was worked. but i didn't find the smoothness or easy to handle like `css3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81453/discussion-between-rob-schmuecker-and-3gwebtrain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution from here: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/zxXrzP - thanks every one.

```
body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin: -10% auto 0 auto; /* positioning tweak */
}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 61.37%; 
}

.ryu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  background:  url('http://bennet.org/images/codepen/ryu-sprite-demo.png') no-repeat 0 0%;
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: sprite 3.5s steps(45) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  from { background-position: 0 0%; }
  to { background-position: 0 100%; }
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.p {
  margin-top: 120px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```